# Python XML Parser: junk after document element

Tags: python

I'm learning Python at work. I've got a large XML file with data similar to this:

**testData3.xml File**

```
<r><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c></c><c></c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c></r>
<r><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c></c><c></c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c></r>
```

I have copied an XML parser out of one of my Python books that works in gathering the data when the data file contains only one line. As soon as I add a second line of data, the script fails when it runs.

Python script that I'm running (xmlReader.py):

```
    from xml.dom.minidom import parse, Node
    xmltree = parse('testData3.xml')
    for node1 in xmltree.getElementsByTagName('c'):
        for node2 in node1.childNodes:
            if node2.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE:
                print(node2.data)
```

I'm looking for some help on how to write the loop so that my xmlReader.py continues through the entire file instead of just one line. I get the following errors when I run this script:

Errors during execution:

```
xxxx@xxxx:~/xxxx/xxxx> python xmlReader.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xmlReader.py", line 2, in <module>
    xmltree = parse('testData3.xml')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/_xmlplus/dom/minidom.py", line 1915, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/_xmlplus/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 926, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(fp)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/_xmlplus/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
    parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: junk after document element: line 2, column 0
xxxx@xxxx:~/xxxx/xxxx>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your example data is not valid XML.  A valid XML document should have a single root element; this is true for a single line of the file, where `<r>` is the root element, but not true when you add a second line, because each line is contained within a separate `<r>` element, but there is no global parent element in the file.

Either construct valid XML, for example:

```
<root>
    <r><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c><c></c><c></c><c>something1</c><c>something1</c></r>
    <r><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c><c></c><c></c><c>something2</c><c>something2</c></r>
</root>
```

or parse the file line by line:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
f = open('testData3.xml'):
    for line in f:
        xmltree = parseString(line)
        ...  
f.close()
```